# wordpress wpdb->update not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I can't update with wpdb->update

here is my code :

```
$tweet = $_POST['tweet'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$wpdb->update( $table_name, array('id' => $id , 'tweet' => $tweet ), array( 'id' => $id ),array("%d","%s"), array("%d") );
```

Nothing wrong i think , but i can't update

thanks advanced

Answer (score 6):

```
$data_update = array('title' => $title ,'parent_id' => $parent_id);
$data_where = array('id' => $id);
$wpdb->update($table_name , $data_update, $data_where);
```

Simple & working ;)